# Data in string - how to get Hours with functions for datatime?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have:

```
var datatime = '2012-01-25 07:44:00';
```

How can i make object Datatime with this, and get only Hours? In php is option ->format("H"). And here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`datetime.substr(11,2)` will give you the hour. Is there any reason you need to go to a Date object in the middle?

Edit: The alternative with the Date object:

```
var datetime = '2012-01-25 07:44:00';
var date = new Date(datetime.replace(' ','T'));
alert(date.getHours());
```

You need to replace the space in the string with a T to make it work reliably. This is the ISO 8601 date format (albeit without a timezone on the end)

Comment: i would like use object, but thanks. Maybe i use this in future.

Comment: Updated my answer to include working code - two working options there now ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var datetime = '2012-01-25 07:44:00';
var date = new Date(datetime);
alert(date.getHours());
```

**Edit:** since IE does not support the `'Y-m-d H:i:s'` format, but the format `'m/d/Y H:i:s'` has no problem. You have to turn to `'m/d/Y H:i:s'` format first.

Comment: `var date = new Date(datetime.replace(' ','T'));`

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date("2012-01-25 07:44:00").getHours()
```

Comment: `new Date("2012-01-25T07:44:00").getHours()`